# ADO.NET Columns names

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

I'm trying to get the column names using the code below but it returns a weird stuff... It returns a lot of "properties" (including the column name), all I want is a list of the columns names in the resultset. Am I doing something wrong ?

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

DataRow myField = schema.Rows[0];
   //For each property of the field...
   foreach (DataColumn myProperty in schema.Columns)
   {
      host.WriteLine("##--> " + myProperty.ColumnName + " = " + myField[myProperty].ToString());
   }
```

Thanks in advance people :)

Miloud B.

Comment: Why not use `myField.Columns["ColumnName"];` to get the column name & ignore the rest of the properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

   //For each property of the field...
   foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
   {
      host.WriteLine("##--> " + row["ColumnName"]);
   }
```

Note: I am writing this code without IDE. Please be kind.

Comment: Dude! Thank you... I was using this in a weird way. Thank you

Comment: What command would have been used to construct cmd in this case?  Does it matter?  Does it even need to be a command that would execute without errors?